# Setting up two rows on a left and right sides of a horizontal center using CSS

Tags: css

I am facing a same problem. I'm trying to create two separate rows **(marked as red background color)** to be aligned horizontally in the center. One of the row on the left side of center part, and second one on the right side of the center part.

Do I need to add something or change some values? I've been trying to do this for 2 hours now.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

```css
.others {
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 70%;
background-color: #d0d0d0;
height: 500px;
margin: auto;
padding: 40px 15% 20px 15%;
display: table;
}

.others p {
margin: 0px;
height: 300px;
float: left;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<DIV CLASS="others">
  <P ID="leftside">
 News will be shown here as they appear.
  </P>
  <P ID="rightside">
 Here you will be able to see our products.
  </P>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        

        
            .others {
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 70%;
            background-color: #d0d0d0;
            height: 500px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 40px 15% 20px 15%;
            display: table;
            }
        
            .others p {
            margin: 0px auto;
            height: 300px;
        width:50%;
    display-inline-block;
text-align:center;
            float: left;
            background-color: red;
            }
        
        
        
            <DIV CLASS="others">
              <P ID="leftside">
             News will be shown here as they appear.
              </P>
              <P ID="rightside">
             Here you will be able to see our products.
              </P>
            </DIV>
```

Comment: Thank you! Just the code that I needed. Appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know how I could make the two rows centered horizontally if they were 40% and not 50%, so that they would not float to the left?

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me just by removing float:left; and add display:table-cell; to .others p.
 [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/s1z49Lvx/2/)

```
.others p {
margin: 0px;
height: 300px;
background-color: red;
display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.others p {
margin: 0px;
height: 300px;
background-color: red;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Not working for some reason, it just puts the blocks together :/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide to p a width value because you are floating the p elements to the left, every p element into the container will get out of the normal document flow and flow from left to right.
Just add width: 50% to every p element. like this:

```
.others p {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 300px;
 float: left;
 background-color: red;
 width:50%;
 }
```

Also provide a clearfix or `overflow:hidden;` to the `.others` in order to contain the floated elements within it's body.

Here is a **[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0FIHpL?p=preview)** to work with

**Edit:** Almost forgot. If you want to gain control onto your layout, provide also a min-width and a max-width value to the body container, so it doesn't strech to much on wide screens, nor it is contained to much on narrower screens. Also, try a css framework, like bootstrap. It will give you fine control onto your layout.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i think you shouldnt use `<p>` for positioning.

use `<div>` instead.

also using `float:left` or `float:right` might solve your problem.

Read up on using floating items here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Also, when using floats, browsers will assume there is nothing inside your 'container' `<div>`.

So i'd also suggest you read up on using css attribute `overflow`.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Thank you so much, I needed that overflow for later part. Would take me pretty long to find it otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .others 
    {
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 70%;
      background-color: #d0d0d0;
      height: 500px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 40px 15% 20px 15%;
      display: table;
    }


    #leftside 
    {
        display:inline-block;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 300px;
        width:50%;
        float: left;
        background-color: red;
    }


   #rightside
    {
        display:inline-block;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 300px;
        width:50%;
        float: right;
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<DIV CLASS="others">
  <P ID="leftside">
 News will be shown here as they appear.
  </P>
  <P ID="rightside">
 Here you will be able to see our products.
  </P>
</DIV>
```